# RANSAC with affine transformation + matlab

Tags: matlab, image-stitching, ransac

I need to implement the RANSAC algo for image Stitching purpose in matlab.
    I have best matching points from two images in bestMatches matrix (2 x 500)
    Now I need to implement RANSAC, this is what I have done so far.I have placed comment as to what needs to be done, can anyone please help me implement it as whole. I have tried really hard for days to do this but with no success. Please help.

```
% ---- run RANSAC  ----
% define RANSAC parameters
threshDistBetPoints = 0.1;
numOfIteration = 50;
numOfRandomPoints = 3;
inlierRatio = 0.6;

% output parameters of RANSAC
best_transform = [];
best_num_inliers = 0;

% Plot the data points
for i=1:numOfIteration
%    1) select 3 random points
        idx = randperm(size(bestMatches,2),numOfRandomPoints); 
        sample = bestMatches(:,idx); 

%    2) compute affine transform T'

%    3) take all 500 matching points
        % map all Q(right image) to P'(left image) (transformation)
        % Compute distances between P' and P point (Left Image) 
        % compute no. of inliers
%    4) store the currently best affine transform
        % output of first iteration - T' and no. of inliers     
        if inlierNum >= best_num_inliers 
             best_num_inliers =  inlierNum
        if end
for end
% End of algorithm best transform = T' with largest numbers of inliers
% stitch function - already implemented

Additional information 
sample =

        3677        6527        2759
        3413        6343        2485
```

Comment: You need to compute the homography based on the points you selected. This site has all these algorithms implemented: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/. You can use those as a guide. Otherwise, ask a specific question about a piece of the code that you are stuck on - here you are just asking for help with the entire implementation.

Comment: Sorry, its my first time using stack overflow, i am stuck at the point where I need to perform affine transform T' in the iteration. My input is only the 3 pair of points (sample) of 2 x 3 matrix.